# Managing state when changing backgroundImage

Tags: reactjs

In state I'm setting background image with a photo and I wanted to do 2 buttons, one is changing background image to another photo and another is setting background image back to the first photo.
Here is piece of my code:

```
\\index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";
import logo1 from "./modules/images/one.jpg";

ReactDOM.render(
  <App bgImage={`url(${logo1})`} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```
\\App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./modules/NavBar";
import logo1 from "./modules/images/one.jpg";
import logo2 from "./modules/images/night.jpg";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      bgImage: props.bgImage //so here I set the backroundImage with logo1, because I want to logo1 to be on the start of application, but when I change to logo2 I want to have that logo2 even when I refresh page ( but when I do it, constructor of App is setting it to the logo1. So maybe, can I save that logo even when the App is reloading to get the latest logo ?
    };
  }

  ChangeToLightMode = e => {
    this.setState({
      bgImage: `url(${logo1})`
    });
  };

  ChangeToDarkMode = e => {
    this.setState({
      bgImage: `url(${logo2})`
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              minHeight: "100vh",
              flexDirection: "column",
              backgroundImage: this.state.bgImage,
              height: "100%",
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            <NavBar
              ChangeToDarkMode={this.ChangeToDarkMode}
              ChangeToLightMode={this.ChangeToLightMode}
            />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
\\NavBar.js

import React, { Component } from "react";

class NavBar extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Menu fixed="top" inverted>

          <Menu.Menu position="right">
            <Menu.Item onClick={this.props.ChangeToDarkMode}>
              DarkMode
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item onClick={this.props.ChangeToLightMode}>
              LightMode
           </Menu.Item>
          </Menu.Menu>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I implemented a way that I can change background photo but when I click for example logo in my application and the constructor of App is called it is setting my bgImage to the first photo even when I had second photo and I know it. But I want only the first photo to be set in constructor in the start of the application, after it I want to have the photo according to which method I use. So should I store somewhere the bgImage state and do something with it in App constructor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default value for `bgImage` needs to be determined *before* `App` is rendered, then usually you would do this by passing a [prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) into the component e.g.

```
<App bgImage={`url(${logo1})`} />
```

Then in the constructor, you can set this as the default state

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bgImage: props.bgImage
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Above the App component I have Index where I did this:  ReactDOM.render(
  <App bgImage={`url(${logo1})`} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
).  (Normally i had only <App/> here). But in my application its seems that when I access another route like /dashboard or etc my appllication refreshes, so even when I used your solution in index.js it still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @db14 sorry but without seeing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't really offer much else. However, regardless any solution will come back to this being the way to get default state into a component.

Comment: I edited my question, so now you have all the minimal code. Added also comment to clarify my problem

Comment: @db14 ok so reading your comment, yes, what you are basically asking for is the ability to save the last known background - you have various options there from storing in a DB at the backend and passing the setting down when you render the client to just storing locally in `window.localStorage` - either way, this will involve some form of persistent storage. But the answer still stands, you would pull said setting from whatever store and pass it as a prop to your component.